# regId is always empty

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm

I'm currenlty implementing GCM into my app. I used the tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) as a start point.

The problem is that my `regId` is always `null`:

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

if (regId.equals(""))
{
    GCMRegistrar.register(this, "627xxxx78");
}
else
{
    if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this))
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Already registered regId : " + regId );
    }
    else
    {
        final Context context = this;

        mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                boolean registered =
                        ServerUtilities.register(context, regId);

                if (!registered)
                {
                    GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                mRegisterTask = null;
            }
        };

        mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
    }
}
```

In the code above, `ServerUtilities.register` is never called because  `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this)`; always returns an empty string.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your manifest file

Comment: What are you getting as a result of your registration request in your `GCMIntentService`?

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue. Add the following in your application manifest file:

```xml
         package="yourApplicationPackage"

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
     <permission
        android:name="yourApplicationPackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
       android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="yourApplicationPackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
   <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="yourApplicationPackage" />
         </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
     <service android:name="yourApplicationPackage.GCMIntentService"/>
```

Must keep this "yourApplicationPackage.GCMIntentService" in application package

yourApplicationPackage.GCMIntentService code is like this.

```
     public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService  {


@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


 }

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
     GcmServer.register(context, registrationId);
}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your emulator or device is signed in with Google Account. I encountered the same problem. I simply signed in the device's google account, and lolz, I got the regId.